# I keep getting this error in my Discord Bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm new to making a Discord.js bot and I keep getting this error:
the bot is online now!

```
HIT
C:\Users\kerix\Desktop\MrMiner\bot\index.js:20
    let commandMethod = commands.get(name);
                        ^

ReferenceError: commands is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\kerix\Desktop\MrMiner\bot\index.js:20:25)
    at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\kerix\Desktop\MrMiner\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:74:12)
    at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\kerix\Desktop\MrMiner\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\kerix\Desktop\MrMiner\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:351:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\kerix\Desktop\MrMiner\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\kerix\Desktop\MrMiner\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\kerix\Desktop\MrMiner\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\kerix\Desktop\MrMiner\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:1137:20)
```

My code is:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { token } = require('./config.js');
const Bot = new Discord.Client({intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]})
require("./slash-register")()

Bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("The Bot Is Online Now!")

    let commands = Bot.application.commands;

})

Bot.on('interactionCreate',async interaction => {
    console.log("HIT")
    if(!interaction.isCommand) return;
    let name = interaction.commandName;
    let options = interaction.options;

    let commandMethod = commands.get(name);
    if(!commandMethod) return;

    await interaction.deferReply();

    commandMethod(Bot, interaction)
})

Bot.login(token)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: 1. That is a warning, not an error. 2. Have you tried doing exactly what the message tells you? Using `'messageCreate'` instead of `'message'`?

Comment: The OP's error is not a deprecation warning about using `message` instead of `messageCreate`. It's this: 
`ReferenceError: commands is not defined at Client.`

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the variable `commands` in the `ready` handler, so it will only be accessible in the `ready` handler. Define it outside to be able to access it in the `interactionCreate` handler:

```js
let commands;

Bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("The Bot Is Online Now!")

    commands = Bot.application.commands;

})

Bot.on('interactionCreate',async interaction => {
    console.log("HIT")
    if(!interaction.isCommand()) return;
    let name = interaction.commandName;
    let options = interaction.options;

    let commandMethod = commands.get(name);
    if(!commandMethod) return;

    await interaction.deferReply();

    commandMethod(Bot, interaction)
})

Bot.login(token)
```

That should fix the specific error you are getting.